# CSS Font won't load

Tags: css, fonts, pyrocms

I'm trying to load the Journal Font but for whatever strange reason it won't load.

```
@font-face {  
  font-family: Brandon Grotesque;  
  src: url(/addons/shared_addons/themes/axium/fonts/brandon-grotesque.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {  
  font-family: Journal;  
  src: url(/addons/shared_addons/themes/axium/fonts/journal.ttf) format("ttf");
}

body {
  font-family: Journal;
}
```

Brandon Grotesque works but Journal doesnt

I downloaded it from: http://www.dafont.com/journal.font

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format identifier at the end is wrong:

```
format("ttf");
```

It should be `format("truetype")`, like Brandon Grotesque.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, change ttf to truetype:

```
src: url(/addons/shared_addons/themes/axium/fonts/brandon-grotesque.ttf) format("truetype");
```

then, make sure its in the right place by checking developer tools (f12 in chrome) [image]

whats more, you have to know that not every browser supports ttf format, you can check it out here:
http://caniuse.com/ttf

also, you need to know that fonts render differently in windows, macos/linux, and font might not look as appealing in chrome under windows as it does in macos/linux